# Add html span binded with onclick function in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to add a span with different icons based on a flag, with the onclick event that call an inside function defined in component ts.

```
testfunc(){
 console.log("it works")
}

flagToIcon(flag: boolean) {
    switch (flag) {
      case true:
       return `<span 
        class="isp-font-2x isp-font-lock cursor-pointer cursor-pointer" ${(onclick)}=${this.testfunc()}></span>`;
        
      case false:
        return `<span "
        class="isp-font-2x isp-font-edit-pencil-n cursor-pointer" ${(onclick)}=${this.testfunc()}></span>`;
    }
  }
```

I'm able to differentiate the cases and the html is returned, however the span tag is rendered without the onclick function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "angular" and "angularjs" are not the same. Your tags are confusing. I suspect you mean just `angular`.

Comment: figure out why the flag is `false`.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, the Icons were rendered accordingly. It's the onclick that doesn't work. It don't exist at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try with ngClass :

```
  [ngClass]="{
    isp-font-lock: flag,
    isp-font-edit-pencil-n: !flag
  }"
```

In HTML use (click) not onClick

Example:

```
<span (click)="flagToIcon()"><i [ngClass]="{
        isp-font-lock: flag,
        isp-font-edit-pencil-n: !flag
      }"></i></span>
```

I don't know your version but in Angular use [(click)](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding#binding-to-events) and [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) can resolve your issue